# Spring mvc: show error message thrown by invalid form input

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to show the exception messages of the exceptions thrown in the domain classes. Right now it shows `Property name threw exception; nested exception is ucll.spacex.domain.DomainException: Invalid Rocket Name` when trying to fill in a form to add an entity to the database without filling in the name. I only want it to show, in this example, `Invalid Rocket Name`

Method of controller that adds the entity to database:

```
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addRocket";
    }
    service.addRocket(rocket);
    return "redirect:/rockets.htm";
```

setName() of this entity:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if(name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new DomainException("Invalid Rocket Name");
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

Form to add an entity to database (first 2 lines):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="rocket" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rockets.htm">
    <form:errors path="*"/>
```

Comment: add the code how you are trying to show the exception

Comment: I added the method of the controller that adds the entity to the database. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm referring to your first sentence - "I'm trying to show the exception messages of the exceptions thrown in the domain classes." - where and how are you trying to do that?

Comment: With the form:errors tag. But I only want the exception message, right now it show the full error

Comment: It should be in the question already, at the bottom

Comment: Don't throw  exception, do Custom Validation, Have a look at this link [https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-validator-example/](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-validator-example/)

Comment: @ShantaramTupe So I should not check on valid arguments in the setters of my domain classes?

Comment: If you go through example, argument validations are checked in a class which implements `Validator`...,

Comment: @ShantaramTupe It works, thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that, you are welcome